# How do you (or can you) translate useMemo to a useReducer?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native

I know how to translate `useState` to `useReducer` but I was wondering is it possible to do something similar with `useMemo`?

I am trying to debug some code where I'm getting extra renders due to a useMemo update, but I can't tell from the React Native Debugger which of the elements in the memo's dependency list is triggering the change.

Answer (score 1):

`useMemo` is for caching result of a calculation in between renders, not for storing state, `useMemo` and `useState/useReducer` are different things, read more at React beta docs [useMemo hook](https://beta.reactjs.org/apis/react/useMemo).